# env command shows 3 times same path

Tags: command-line, path, osx-lion, env

When i run `env` it shows 3 times `/usr/bin` under PATH . Same for every path under  `PATH` title. 
For example - my scala bin directory shows 3 times . 
However, in my .bash_profile, it is written just one time . Also its not in .bashrc also. I need to make this 3 occurrences to 1, as even though I remove some path under PATH in .bash_profile, it still shows 2 times , which means that path is still set.
 `echo $PATH` shows the same thing.  
And , if it matters I am using macosx.

Comment: So… what's the problem with that? And how is programming related? Should be a question on SuperUser instead.

Comment: @DarkDust Ok.I will put that up in SuperUser. For how that matters - say I update my scala version and export its path . Now I have two bin directories having  scala . So if i run scala, i am dependent on system to interpret which one it will take. In my preliminary check, its taking the newest one, but other programs dependent on older version are failing . And i reasoned this could be a problem. I may be wrong here, but i need to be sure that this is not the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK..So I found the solution. 
Here is what I was doing :-
 1) `vi ~/.bash_profile`
 2) make changes
3) `source ~/.bash_profile` to see those changes in effect . 
It seems for every editing and subsequent source command, temporarily keeps in current session.
 So , if i made changes 3 times and consequent `source` command, it shows 3 times the same path if i do `echo $PATH` or `env`.
Closing the terminal and restarting it puts back everything to normal. 
So, it was just a matter or restarting the terminal!! 
Clarification :- Different platforms may perform differently. I found macosx-10.7 works this way.

Comment: Rather, the code in your `.bash_profile` does not avoid adding duplicate paths. That's fine, but it doesn't generalize to people whose `.bash_profile` doesn't work that way.

Comment: @tripleee , I havent checked on other platforms. I am using macox-10.7 and it works here this way. I will tag this question properly. And there is nothing wrong in this behavior. Or may be I didnt understand the working of source command properly in the first place... May be i have to look more closely how source command works..

Comment: @tripleee , there is no code written by me in .bash_profile . its standard code provided by apple only..

Answer (score 0):

There are many files that can setup PATH, usually adding to a previously defined $PATH (so as not to miss any important directory).

See for example the guide at http://linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/postlfs/profile.html

You would like to see, amongst possibly others : 
  /etc/profiles
  /etc/bashrc
  ~/.bash_profile
  ~/.bashrc

And **be careful** : don't edit the wrong files or put "login-only things" into a "for non-login shell" file, and vice versa.

Citing the /etc/profile example from the link above, by James Robertson , you can see each file's meaning:

- **/etc/profile** : System wide environment variables and startup programs.
- **/etc/bashrc** : System wide aliases and functions should go in /etc/bashrc.
- **~/.bash_profile** : Personal environment variables and startup programs should go into ~/.bash_profile.
- **~/.bashrc** : Personal aliases and functions should go into ~/.bashrc.

(warning: changing /etc/profile has to be made CAREFULLY. It's used in many low level stages of bootup, and is inherited by almost everything running in your OS, so be careful that a small "unhamrful" change may wreak heavoc in your system)